# Linux Live CD only works when Windows is in Legacy mode?

Tags: linux, boot, bios, uefi

I have asked a similar question before and no one was able to help me but I think it was because I wasn't phrasing it properly. This is a better restatement of the question. I have Windows 8 and Linux Mint dual booted on my pc. When I tried to boot the Linux from a CD ROM only, it would give me the following error:

```
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'hd1'
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

The Linux Mint works fine but otherwise, but it gives this error when I try to boot from CD. The boot Linux from CD only worked when I changed the Windows to Legacy mode in the BIOS settings. When I changed it back to UEFI, it would give the same error. Why is this? How can I fix it? I am somewhat new so is there anything else I should know about all of this?

NOTE: I changed the Linux into UEFI mode using boot-repair but that still did not solve the problem when I tried to boot from CD ROM.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and any of the 1000s of results for linux UEFI you can find on google.

Comment: Do you know if Mint even supports UEFI. I can only assume the problem is that there isn't EFI boot information on the "Live CD"

Comment: @terdon I used that link and I used boot-repair to change the Linux into UEFI mode, the Live CD still didn't work which is why I am asking here.

Comment: @Ramhound I changed the Linux into UEFI using boot-repair

Comment: @Vee please mention the things you have tried in your question, we can't know what you've done. Now, what do you mean you changed Linux to UEFI? You mean your installed system? Did you "In your BIOS, disable QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT). If you have Windows8, also disable FastStartup." as suggested by the guide I linked to?

Comment: Just to configrm you are booting a EFI supported `Live CD` and your UEFI BIOS is set to load said device in Non-Legacy Mode. When you do this it fails to load, when you switch your BIOS to load the device in Legacy mode it works except for the error above?  The error indicates your Live CD is trying to load information on your main hdd which is odd if your booting from a Live CD

Comment: @terdon In the link you provided, I followed the steps under "Converting Ubuntu into EFI Mode" using boot repair. After doing that, I made my HDD boot in EFI mode from my BIOS settings. After trying that, I still was not able to boot from the CD. As for the QuickBoot and SRT, I was unable to find them in the BIOS. Secure boot is disabled though.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, I get the errors when I set it to boot in UEFI mode in the BIOS settings. When I change the Windows 8 into Legacy mode, I get no errors with the Linux CD and it works fine.

Comment: @Vee - Alright..The errors basically indicate the `Live CD` image does not support booting as a UFI disk.  You shouldn't be touching how your system treats your hdd.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, so does that mean every time I would want to boot from Linux CD, I would have to change into Legacy mode? Is there no other way to do it or do I just wait for them to make an EFI compatible version or something?

Comment: @Vee - You should be able to make it EFI compatible yourself if that is indeed the problem it only involves providing the required files on the disk.  I will have to look at what the .iso looks like later.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Mint CD you're using either has buggy EFI support or that support has an incompatibility with your particular computer. The main Mint distribution has long supported EFI, but EFI support is new enough that bugs and incompatibilities are far from rare. It's possible you could overcome this problem by upgrading your computer's firmware to the latest version, by using a different version of Mint (you don't say which one you're using), by preparing a USB flash drive and booting from it, or by modifying the boot loader on a USB flash drive. If you want more practical advice, please say what version of Mint you're using and what your computer's make and model are. Posting your problem to the [Mint forum](http://forums.linuxmint.com) might also be in order.

Fortunately, for most purposes using an emergency Linux CD in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode is not a problem, even if your regular installation boots in EFI mode. The main reasons to want to boot a live CD in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode are to install the OS or to manage a boot loader setup using the `efibootmgr` utility. Based on your question, the former task is already done (although that begs the question of how you did it). Managing boot loaders can be done using the Windows `bcdedit` command, using an EFI shell's `bcfg` command, or sometimes using an EFI's built-in user interface. See the [Installing rEFInd Manually](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#manual) section of the rEFInd documentation for more information on most of these tools. (The same principles apply to other boot programs, not just to rEFInd.)

Comment: My Mint's version is 15 so it's the latest one. It's an HP Envy 1225-dx, runs on an i5-3230m, 8gb of RAM. And yes, the reason this was a concern to me was this problem did not occur when I first installed the Linux. I do not remember having to change the boot into Legacy. And yes, I will check out Mint forum.